# Unable to connect and get Sharepoint data from C# .Net Core App

Tags: .net, sharepoint-online, .net-6.0, microsoft365, pnp-js

While using **pnp.Framework** in .Net 6 environment. I need authenticated client context to get Sharepoint Data but facing 403forbidden while running **context.ExecuteQuery()**.

I want to use the clientId and clientSecret mode of authentication for getting data from my client to my environment but facing 403 forbidden request.

I registered App in the particular Azure Active Directory and added the following permissions.

[image]

```
using PnP.Framework;
using System.Security;
using System.Web;

namespace SharePointOnlinePNPProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string appID= "appId/clientId";
            string tenantId = "<tenantId>";
            string clientSecret = "";
            string queueTestingLink = "Input sharepoint url";
            Uri site = new Uri("https://clientDomain.sharepoint.com");
            string filePath= "/Shared Documents/Case Studies"

            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in passcode)
            {
                password.AppendChar(c);
            }
            var scopes = new string[] { hostLink + ".default" };
            try
            {
               
                using (var context = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(site.OriginalString, appID, clientSecret))
                {
                    var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
                   
                   
                    context.Load(folder);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you fixed the issue?

Comment: I Fixed this issue by using App id and secret created from Sharepoint Admin center. will post the answer soon @ursaciuc

Answer (score 5):

Use **Sharepoint Admin Center** to create App and use that **App Id** and **Client secret** to get authenticated client context. I was able to access data in the same code posted above.

Follow below steps to create Client Id and Secret for your organisations sharepoint tenant.

## Step 1:

- Go to your organisations AppRegNew page: For example [https://organisation.sharepoint.com]/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx
- Generate Client Id, Client Secret and save it in a secure place
- Provide a suitable tittle
- Provide domain name and redirect uri (Can be anything. Even
  [www.LocalHost.com](http://www.LocalHost.com))
- Check below sample AppRegNew page form

[image]

## Step 2:

- Go to [https://organisation.sharepoint.com]/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
- Enter app Id (AKA Client Id) and press lookup.
- Copy paste the below text in Permission Request XML and save

```html
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

[image]

## Step 3:

- You will receive a page similar to the one below. Click “Trust it” and complete the process.
- Use the Client Id and Client Secret we saved in first step for creating sharepoint pnp context and accessing the files in that organisation's tenant

[image]

## In Conclusion:

- The above steps will create and add necessary permissions for our client credentials.
- Using this credentials we can create client context with pnp c# library code as provided in the question.
- Microsoft stopped AzureAD App access for authentication of sharepoint AppOnly Access. Using that method is useless unless we are willing to add self signed certificates in AzureAd.

For More Info :
Please follow the below blog to configure app and get credentials.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

[image]

Comment: we made it work with the self signed certificates. The certificate was generated in a vault then registered in azure ad.

Comment: Good to know certificate method works too. @ursaciuc thanks for ur comment. You can try SharePoint admin centre as it can help to connect with multiple tenants seamlessly and fast .

Comment: Solution works like a charm, except that in step 2, it is necessary to go to organization-admin.sharepoint.com to grant the permissions. Thank you.